# windows 8 IShellIconOverlayIdentifier shell extension not working properly

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-shell

I have an application where i want to have icon overlays for specific files and folders.

For this purpose i've written a shell extension that implements the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier interface. Its written in c++ / Qt ([activeqt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/activeqt.html)) as a dll that connects to the application in question using tcp to query the application to decide wether to show the icon overlay or not. Its buildt much the same way [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32104-howto-making-a-windows-shell-extension-with-qt-open-source-edition) is.

It works fine in XP/Vista/7 but it wont work in windows 8.

In windows 8 the dll is loaded. I can see it in [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and also as a part of debugging it also logs output to a file so i can see whats happening and infer whats not.

Using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) i can also see thats its registered, not disabled and in general everything looks ok.

The class declaration looks more or less like this:

```
class Q_DECL_EXPORT OverlayClass :
    public QAxAggregated,
    public IShellIconOverlayIdentifier{
public:
    // Implements IUnknown
    QAXAGG_IUNKNOWN; 

    JShellOverlayWorking();

    // Implements IShellIconOverlayIdentifier
    STDMETHOD(GetOverlayInfo)(LPWSTR pwszIconFile, int cchMax, int *pIndex, DWORD* pdwFlags);
    STDMETHOD(GetPriority)(int* pPriority);
    STDMETHOD(IsMemberOf)(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib);

    //pure virtual from QAxAggregated
    long queryInterface(const QUuid &iid, void**iface); 
};
```

Whats happens on XP/Vista/7 :

- that explorer on load first call queryInterface() and gets an S_OK if iid == IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier and E_NOINTERFACE for all other iid's
- and then it goes on to call GetOverlayInfo() to initialize stuff. Get the icon file path etc.
- And then as the shell needs to it calls IsMemberOf() to see if it should display the icon for a file or folder.

What happens on windows 8 :

- that explorer on load calls queryInterface() and gets an S_OK when iid == IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier and E_NOINTERFACE for all other iid's

And nothing else. queryInterface() is getting called, but after that nothing happens. I can see my application connecting successfully to the tcp socket created by the shell extension and IPC is working( i can send data back and forth between the application and the dll, but again. Nothing else happens. Explorer is not using the implemented interface.

The dll is registered using:

```
regsvr32.exe shellext.dll
```

and the registry key below is also added

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\Shellextname ( value = CSLID )
```

for testing on windows 8 i've also added the following key to

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved
```

with my shell extensions CSLID as the name and data = Shellextname ( as above in the previous key) though this doesn't seem to matter on XP/Vista/7 so i'm guessing its inconsequential here as well.

Again, this works on every windows( >= xp) except windows 8.

What am i missing? Where do i go from here to find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem was that the registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{myguid}\InprocServer32
        ThreadingModel = Apartment
```

as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was not set by regsvr32.exe. I guess previous windows versions ignored this if it wasn't set, but windows 8 required it. Setting it manually worked.